# How to fix images link became temporary

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently having a bad time in my website.

All my images link became temporary.

from `http://sample_domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image1.jpg`

to `http://cfff88608e2042670.temporary.link/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image1.jpg`

And the image is not showing anymore.

Can someone help me!

Comment: What have you done just before? This is not a normal Wordpress behavior

Comment: This project was just turn over to me. I have no idea what happen on the previous developer before.

Comment: Search the database for the temporary link, and replace it with your current domain name

Answer (score 0):

open phpmyadmin go to wp_post and fire the below query in your wp_post table it will be solved

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content, ''yoursite.com, blog.yoursite.com''));
```

Comment: I've seen this already, but I'm thinking about not updating any fields in my database.